# Android is not Reading JSON Array with name

Tags: php, android, json

it seems that my Activity is having problem with the JSON array name

here is my activity :

```
package com.example.raamzz.booksharev2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;





import com.example.raamzz.booksharev2.CustomListAdapter;
import com.example.raamzz.booksharev2.AppController;
import com.example.raamzz.booksharev2.Book;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

public class Romance extends AppCompatActivity {


    String TITLES[] = {"Home","Events","Books","Wishlist","Nearby","Edit Profile "};
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.home,R.drawable.events,R.drawable.books,R.drawable.wishlist,R.drawable.taxi,R.drawable.edit};








    private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle



    String UserID,UserFN,UserEmail,UserPassword,UserAddress,UserPhone,UserGender,UDOB,ProfPicture;

    public  static final String DEFUALT_SHARED="N/A";


    //---------------------------------//


    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = Romance.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://mybookshare.com/app/GetRomanceBooks.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_romance);
        SharedPreferences sp =getSharedPreferences("UserData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        UserID = sp.getString("UserID", DEFUALT_SHARED );
        UserFN=sp.getString("UserFN",DEFUALT_SHARED);
        UserEmail=sp.getString("UserEmail",DEFUALT_SHARED);
        ProfPicture=sp.getString("ProfPicture",DEFUALT_SHARED);


        //-----------------------------------//

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, bookList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        //-----------------------------------//





        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(ProfPicture, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);



    /* Assinging the toolbar object ot the view
    and setting the the Action bar to our toolbar
     */
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,UserFN,UserEmail,decodedByte);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView


        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(Romance.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

        });



        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());



                if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){

                    int position=recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);

                    switch (position){

                        case 1:
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Romance.this, UserProfileHOME.class);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Case 1 in home  to event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Romance.this.startActivity(intent1);
                            break;


                        case 2:
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Romance.this, Events.class);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Case 2 in home  to event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Romance.this.startActivity(intent2);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Intent intent3 = new Intent(Romance.this, Books.class);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Case 3 in home  to books", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Romance.this.startActivity(intent3);
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            Intent intent4 = new Intent(Romance.this, Wishlist.class);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Case 4 in home  to wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Romance.this.startActivity(intent4);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Intent intent5 = new Intent(Romance.this, Nearby.class);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Case 5 in home  to nearby", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Romance.this.startActivity(intent5);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Intent intent6 = new Intent(Romance.this, Editprofile.class);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Case 6 in home  to editprof", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Romance.this.startActivity(intent6);
                            break;

                    }

                    Drawer.closeDrawers();


                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });



        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }



        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State


        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//


        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Book book = new Book();
                                book.setTitle(obj.getString("BTitle"));
                                book.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("BCoverpath"));
                                book.setAuthor(obj.getString("BAuthor"));
                                book.setEdition(obj.getString("BEdition"));



                                // adding movie to movies array
                                bookList.add(book);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }








    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

and here is my php which is sending the json array :

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');


$response = array();


require_once('init.php');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *FROM book WHERE IDCateOf = 8") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

$response["books"]= array();    

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


        $books["BID"] = $row["BID"];
        $book["BTitle"] = $row["BTitle"];
        $book["BAuthor"] = $row["BAuthor"];
        $book["BCoverpath"] =$row["BCoverpath"];
        $book["BEdition"] = $row["BEdition"];



           array_push( $response["books"], $book);

    }



    echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES && JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
?>
```

the array that is generated using this php script is like this :

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "BTitle": "Attachments",
      "BAuthor": "Rainbow Rowell",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/1.jpg",
      "BEdition": "2th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Maybe Someday",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/2.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Me Before You : A Novel (Movie Tie-In)",
      "BAuthor": "Jojo Moyes",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/3.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Hopeless",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/4.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Finding Cinderella",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/5.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "November Nine",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/6.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Ugly Love",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/7.jpg",
      "BEdition": "3th"
    }
  ]
}
```

which my android activity is not recognizing because it json array must be like this :

```
 [
    {
      "BTitle": "Attachments",
      "BAuthor": "Rainbow Rowell",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/1.jpg",
      "BEdition": "2th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Maybe Someday",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/2.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Me Before You : A Novel (Movie Tie-In)",
      "BAuthor": "Jojo Moyes",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/3.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Hopeless",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/4.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Finding Cinderella",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/5.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "November Nine",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/6.jpg",
      "BEdition": "1th"
    },
    {
      "BTitle": "Ugly Love",
      "BAuthor": "Colleen Hoover",
      "BCoverpath": "http://mybookshare.com/books/7.jpg",
      "BEdition": "3th"
    }
  ]
```

and i tried to make a .json file and i put the last json array without the name and the application worked just fine but i need to solve this problem because i need to get the data dynamically from the database using the php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first JSON is not an array. It's an object with "books" array in it. You need to create appropriate object for this JSON, like:

```
class BookList {
    List<Book> books;
}
```

Here is you modified code to work with that JSON:

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();

                // Parsing json
                JSONArray arr = response.getJSONArray("books");

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                        Book book = new Book();
                        book.setTitle(obj.getString("BTitle"));
                        book.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("BCoverpath"));
                        book.setAuthor(obj.getString("BAuthor"));
                        book.setEdition(obj.getString("BEdition"));



                        // adding movie to movies array
                        bookList.add(book);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        hidePDialog();

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot khalidov i really appreciate it it worked , and i also found another way by tweaking the php script into not sending the array name in the response , now i found two solutions which more than i wanted thanks again :)

Comment: yes i wish to vote for you but i am new to the stack overflow and my reputation below 15 , believe me i tried voting for you but it didn't work :(

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice that.